# WCF 4 REST and WCF 4 Data Services

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, rest

We have just developed a set of web services and hosted them as follows:

Hosted Locally : WCF 4 Data Services (has an svc file) with Entity Framework & Linq in the backend accessing an SQL Server database. Lets call this WebDataServices

Hosted Abroad : WCF 4 REST Services (no svc file) with Entity Framework & Linq in the backend to access the WCF Data Services. Lets call this WebFeedServices.

All this worked fine in our UAT environment as everything was local. The moment we hosted the services separately (as described above), we started having issues.

The issue is that the WebFeedServices do not get any data.

In our round of investigations we found out:

a) When we mstsc into the servers abroad and browse the WebDataServices using Internet Explorer, we can see the response xml in the browser.

b) When we mstsc into the servers abroad and browse the WebFeedServices (using Internet Explorer) with an INVALID ID (GetByID using a fake/non-existent ID), we can see the response xml in the browser and it returns a null xml/object. The empty object is due to check that is put in place by us.

c) When we mstsc into the servers abroad and browse the WebFeedServices with a VALID ID (GetByID using a real/existent ID), we do not see the response xml in the browser and it returns a null xml/object.

At first we thought it could be erroneous content in the database tables that could be interfering but that should've shown up in UAT.

We're not sure what else we should be looking at. Both the Web Services are currently hosted on W2K3 server/IIS6 environment and WebFeedServices being RESTful has Wildcard mappings and anonymous authentication configured as well.

Any help or suggestions for the moment would be much appreciated.

Thanks & regards,

Noel

Comment: What is the Http code you get when you try to browse to the WebFeedServices. Try using fiddler to send the request to the FeedService and see the response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to enable tracing on your services and that would give more details on where in the pipeline errors are occuring. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)